# How do I avoid getting build failed error in this Fortran Hello World code

Tags: fortran

```
PRINT*, 'Hello World'
END
```

After typing the above in Fortran for the first time, I get the error below. I can't seem to figure out what to do.

```
cd 'C:\Users\sylvi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/sylvi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/sylvi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o 
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\sylvi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:2: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:C:\Users\sylvi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/main.cpp:21: first defined here
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o: In function `MAIN__':
C:\Users\sylvi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:1: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
C:\Users\sylvi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:1: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
C:\Users\sylvi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:1: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\sylvi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:2: undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_args'
C:\Users\sylvi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:2: undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/sylvi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/sylvi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: Is `PRINT*, 'Hello World' END` your complete code? Is there anything else?

Comment: What does "typing the above in Fortran" mean? What did you execute? What did you click on? Which compiler do you have? Do you use an IDE? Which operating system do you have?

Comment: @PetrH I do not see how that could help with the current issue. There is no programming error in the code presented to us. If the compiler does not compile one Hello world code, it is highly unlikely to compile another one. The program is clearly with incorrect linking of the runtime libraries (libgfortran).

Comment: @VladimirF I was trying to address the *typing in Fortran* part, which could mean anything. But OK, I will delete my comment, it might have been misplaced.

Comment: Your makefile is using a C++ compiler to build a Fortran program.  Try adding an extra rule to go from .f90 to .o